# How can I fix these calculations?

Tags: javascript

I'm taking a number, dividing by 100 and then multiplying it by 100 to have it return to it's original value. Some returned values are a little off however.

```
var num = 57,
    num = num / 100,

    // this should return the number to the original
    // however in this example it returns 56.99999999999999
    num = num * 100;
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/njsdW/

In truth, all I want to do is add two 0's in front of the number, but I'm not always sure where the decimal would be.

EDIT: My solution:

```
var num = 57,
    num = (parseFloat((num / 100).toPrecision(15)));

    // this should return the number to the original
    num = (parseFloat((num * 100).toPrecision(15)));
```

Comment: this is a product of inaccuracies in [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) computations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Anything involving floating point math with normal floats is a cause for grief. Most languages have special libraries for dealing with precision in floats, eg. BigDecimal in Ruby and Java.

Comment: *" all I want to do is add two 0's in front of the number"*... Since this is your actual problem, could you elaborate on this please? Some example input and output would be helpful.

Comment: @Felix Kling, divide by 100. In theory that'll just mean placing two 00's in front of the number.

Comment: @Chaplin: `100` divided by `100` is `1`. Number values don't have a concept of *leading zeros*. You can **format** your number to have leading zeros, but that's something totally different.

Comment: +1 for providing jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must save the precision of your number and restore it after dividing by 100

```
prec = num.length;

// adjust for decimal point
if (num.indexOf('.') != -1)
    prec--;

// adjust for leading zero
if (num < 1)
    prec--;

num /= 100;
self.find('h2').append(num.toPrecision(prec));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njsdW/44/)

Comment: You expect `num` to be a string?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, see jsfiddle: `num = self.find('h1').text()`.

Comment: Not a good variable name then, imho :-) Also, the implicit type conversion of num when `/=100` might be confusing…

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript bignum implementation like [javascript-bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum) or [gmp.js](https://github.com/kripken/gmp.js) to get arbitrary precision. If you want to use gmp.js, you'd have to rewrite your application in C/C++ or write gmp.js bindings for JavaScript. In return, you'd get the battle-tested reliability and optimal algorithmic effenciency from GNU GMP.